# Cannot recognize codecs in c++ code made with open cv

Tags: c++, opencv, qt-creator, codec

If I run a pre-compiled version of a program, it recognizes that my computer has a lot of compression codecs on it. However, if I compile the program myself using my version of python, opencv, etc (which I need to do for complicated reasons), the only recognized compression codec is MJPG. I am not sure if this is an issue with how I am compiling and/or the versions of python etc I am using, something not on path, or even a way in which the program is checking codecs.

Here is how the program checks for codecs:

```
    void backEnd::testCodecSupport()
{
    // This function will test which codecs are supported on host's machine
    cv::VideoWriter testVid;
//    testVid.open("test.avi", -1,20, cv::Size(640, 480), true);
    QVector<QString> possibleCodec({"DIB ", "MJPG", "MJ2C", "XVID", "FFV1", "DX50", "FLV1", "H264", "I420","MPEG","mp4v", "0000", "LAGS", "ASV1", "GREY"});
    for (int i = 0; i < possibleCodec.length(); i++) {
        testVid.open("test.avi", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc(possibleCodec[i].toStdString()[0],possibleCodec[i].toStdString()[1],possibleCodec[i].toStdString()[2],possibleCodec[i].toStdString()[3]),
                20, cv::Size(640, 480), true);
        if (testVid.isOpened()) {
            m_availableCodec.append(possibleCodec[i]);
            qDebug() << "Codec" << possibleCodec[i] << "supported for color";
            testVid.release();
        }
        else
            unAvailableCodec.append(possibleCodec[i]);
    }

}
```

And here are the specs for my computer and what I am using to compile"

- Windows 10 home version 21H2
- program is win32
- Using QT creator with Desktop QT 5.15.2 MSCV2019 32bit
- compiled with microsoft visual c++ compiler
- python 3.1
- opencv 4.5.5

Comment: there should be an `opencv_ffmpegxxx.dll` in your install. make sure, your program can find it at runtime, it includes all video file funcs, and the codecs. also: `print(cv2.getBuildInformation()))`

Comment: @berak I am missing that file and I see it is in the original compiled program, but it still does not work even when I add the file opencv_videoio_ffmpeg455_64.dll to the program folder where the rest of the .dll files are.

Comment: @berak nevermind, I got it!! I had to use the opencv_videoio_ffmpeg455.dll file instead. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @berak in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73042195/cannot-recognize-codecs-in-c-code-made-with-open-cv/73043267#comment129006171_73042195) -- I needed an opencv_videoio_ffmpeg455.dll file in the location I ran the program. Thank you!